# If $AX=\lambda X$ for every eigenvector $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then show that $A=\lambda I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $AX=\lambda X$ for every eigenvector $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then show that $A=\lambda I_n$.

Given, $AX=\lambda X$ for every $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then $(A-\lambda I_n)X=0$ is true for every $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

But how to show $A=\lambda I_n$? Please help.

Comment: If $(A - \lambda I_n)x = 0$ for all $x$, then by definition of being an operator from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$, it is the zero operator.

Comment: Choose the columns of $I$ as $X$.

Comment: In the current form, the statement is not true. It becomes true if this is required to hold for *all* vectors, rather than just for all *eigenvectors*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $\vec e_i$ is the vector of the standard basis with components $\delta_{i,j}$, than
$A\vec e_i$ is  the column $i$ of the matrix $A$.

And we have $A\vec e_i=\lambda \vec e_i=\lambda \delta_{i,j}$, so....

---

For $\vec e_1=[1,0,0]^T$ we have
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}=
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\iff
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\a_{21}\\a_{31}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we can do the same for the other vectors of the basis.

Comment: I shall be grateful if you kindly write the answer in more details.

Comment: I've added to may answer the example for  a matrix acting on $\mathbb{R}^3$. You can easily see how the same works in any vector space.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**$(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for any $x\in \Bbb R^n$ implies $A-\lambda
 I$ maps every $x\in \Bbb R^n$ to $0$, this is exactly the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroMap.html) of a zero transformation.